# Radgrid stop editing but allow paging

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radgrid, telerik-grid

I need a way to stop all editing (insert, update, delete) on a Radgrid but still allow the paging to work.

Ive tried disabling the MasterTableView but this also stops my users from viewing the data.

The only way I can see to do it, is to check if they are allowed to edit in the various handlers for the insert, update and delete commands and take action in there.

It would be nicer to somehow disable the command columns if the user does not have access.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [this approach](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-set-edit-permissions-depending-on-permission-field.html)? Should be applicable for editing operations of any kind.

Comment: Is there a global setting, rather than per-row?